# detect when user check or uncheck row on client side in primefaces datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, primefaces, datatable

I use [this row editing primefaces datatable](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableRowEditing.jsf) and I added the multiple selection feature through [this example](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableRowSelectionRadioCheckbox.jsf)

then I want to detect on client side when the user check or uncheck one row and the number of rows checked at each change

I tried a many ways with firebug .... but no result

here is one of my essays (just for testing):

```
$(function(){                       
                $('.ui-chkbox-box.ui-widget.ui-corner-all.ui-state-default').mousemove(function(){

                    if(('.ui-chkbox-box.ui-widget.ui-corner-all.ui-state-default').hasClass('ui-state-active'))
                        alert('show');
                });
```

do you have any idea

Answer (score 0):

If you just want know when a user clicked a checkbox that is located in a datatable, you can use this code to listen for the click and verify if it is checked or not:

```
jQuery(".ui-chkbox").click(function () {
    if(jQuery(this).find("span").first().hasClass("ui-icon-check"))
        alert("unchecked");            
    else
        alert("checked");
}
```

Notice that the if clause is inverted, it happens because this function will be called before primefaces adds the class "ui-icon-check" to the div.